# ModuleNotFoundError on dataflow job created by CloudFunction

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataflow

Good morning. I have a problem with creating a dataflow job with CloudFunctions.

I have CloudFunctions correctly configured. I am downloading a scripting package (python) from GS.

In the .zip pack I have the following files:
main.py
module01.py
requirements.txt
some_config.conf

on main.py I have:
`from module01 import some_things`

Everything looks good - there is no error on the CloudFunctions side, the dataflow job starts correctly, but the dataflow job worker throws:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module01'`

Comment: which python version are you using?

Comment: @UmairMubeen Python 3.7

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/resources/faq#how_do_i_handle_nameerrors):

> By default, global imports, functions, and variables defined in the
> main session are not saved during the serialization of a Dataflow job.

If you're importing your module `module01` globally:

```
from module01 import some_things

def cloud_function():
  # your function
```

try to import it **locally**, where it is used, instead:

```
def cloud_function():
  from module01 import some_things
  # your function
```